# ECL item fields not accepting special characters

Tags: sites-9.5, ecl-connector

I'm facing an issue with ECL items not loading if the original item contains special characters on some of the fields. All items are processed with a custom AddOn solution. I have tried encoding the text fields as HTML with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` but the problem persists.

Comment: When you say special characters and on some of the fields... a) do you mean all tested fields or it doesn't fail in some fields? b) is the whole item not loading or just the specific fields that are escaped?

Comment: The issue is on any text field, and it causes the whole item to not load.

Comment: Which "special characters" in particular are causing issues?  Do these issues also occur without the "custom AddOn solution"?

Comment: Right now the minimum requirement would be accepting & and ', ideally any language specific such as ė, ł, ü, č, ç, ñ. In order to load the External Content onto the CMS I must use the custom AddOn.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the problem would be in that custom addon, as we routinely test the Tridion with all kinds of characters. If you can give a step-by-step example of how to reproduce the problem (including the exact characters to put in a field), I can give it a try on a vanilla ECL instance to verify my suspicion.

Comment: Whenever we are trying to import an external item that contains the characters & or ' , the item appears onto the CMS but when we open it doesn't load anything on the item and a pop up shows up "Unable to load item".